# ruby adds no path to gems

Tags: ruby, rake, rvm

I use:

1. rvm 1.25.19 (stable)
2. ruby 1.9.3p545

I install gem rake command

```
gem install rake
```

I understand that $LOAD_PATH should contain the paths:

```
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby1.9/gems/rake/lib
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby1.9/gems/rake/bin
```

I execute command:

```
ruby -e 'puts $LOAD_PATH'
```

output:

```
/home/slip/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1
/home/slip/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
/home/slip/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/home/slip/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1
/home/slip/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
/home/slip/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/home/slip/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1
/home/slip/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
```

why path to gem 'rake' don't add?

Answer (score 2):

Installing a gem in Ruby doesn’t automatically add that gem’s files to the load path. When you `require` a file, first the existing load path is searched and if no matching file is found then Rubygems searches the installed gems for the file. If such a gem is found, then it is *activated*, which is when the gem’s `lib` directory is added to the load path.

Here’s an example using the Haml gem:

```
puts "Before:"
puts $LOAD_PATH
puts

require 'haml'
puts "After:"
puts $LOAD_PATH
```

This produces:

```
Before:
/Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1
/Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.8.0
/Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1
/Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.8.0
/Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1
/Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.8.0

After:
/Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib
/Users/matt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/haml-4.0.5/lib
/Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1
/Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.8.0
/Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1
/Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.8.0
/Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1
/Users/matt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.8.0
```

See how the `lib` directories for Tilt (which is a dependency of Haml) and Haml have been added to the start of the load path.

In the case of some gems, such as Rake, this is complicated by the fact they are part of the standard library and so are already on the load path. If you changed the example above to use `require 'rake'` then you wouldn’t see any change in the load path. In this situation you can specify you want to use the gem version with the `gem` method. This activates the gem in question, placing its `lib` directory at the start of the load path so when you later call `require` you will load the correct version.

For example, this script

```
require 'rake'
puts Rake::VERSION
```

produces `0.9.2.2` with Ruby 1.9.3, as that is the version of Rake included in the standard library. However this script:

```
gem 'rake'
require 'rake'
puts Rake::VERSION
```

produces `10.1.1`, since that is the current highest version of the Rake gem installed on my system. You can also specify a particular gem version by providing a second argument to `gem` (this is the same syntax as used in `Gemfiles`). Note that the `gem` method *doesn’t* `require` any files, you have to do that as a separate step.